# Simpson's Composite Rule giving too large values for when n is very large

Tags: c++, math

Using Simpson's Composite Rule to calculate the integral from `2` to `1,000` of `1/ln(x)`, however when using a large `n` (usually around `500,000`), I start to get results that vary from the value my calculator and other sources give me (`176.5644`). For example, when `n = 10,000,000`, it gives me a value of `184.1495`. Wondering why this is, since as n gets larger, the accuracy is *supposed* to increase and not decrease.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// the function f(x)
float f(float x)
{
    return (float) 1 / std::log(x);
}




float my_simpson(float a, float b, long int n)
{
  if (n % 2 == 1) n += 1; // since n has to be even
  float area, h = (b-a)/n;


  float x, y, z;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++)
  {
    x = a + (2*i - 2)*h;
    y = a + (2*i - 1)*h;
    z = a + 2*i*h;
    area += f(x) + 4*f(y) + f(z);
  }

  return area*h/3;
}



int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(20);
    int upperBound = 1'000;
    int subsplits = 1'000'000;

    float approx = my_simpson(2, upperBound, subsplits);

    std::cout << "Output: " << approx << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Update: Switched from floats to doubles and works much better now! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: BTW, could you please clarify which is the `n` you are talking in the question? Is it the one in `main` or the one in `my_simpson`?

Comment: Your code likely suffers from underflow when `n` is large. `float` can only represent 7-8 significant figures.

Comment: @Bob__ talking about the n in my_simpson, I'll edit the post to make it clearer :)

Comment: Also note that `area` isn't initialized (that results in undefined behavior, but not the loss of precision that you are witnessing).

Comment: @Bob__  I remember hearing floats being more precise and faster, which now I look into it isn't exactly the case haha, I changed it to doubles and it works much better now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a real (in mathematical sense) number, a `float` has a limited precision.

A typical IEEE 754 32-bit (single precision) floating-point number binary representation dedicates only 24 bits (one of which is implicit) to the mantissa and that translates in roughly less than 8 decimal significant digits (please take this as a gross semplification).

A `double` on the other end, has 53 significand bits, making it more accurate and (usually) the first choice for numerical computations, these days.

> since as n gets larger, the accuracy is supposed to increase and not decrease.

Unfortunately, that's not how it works. There's a sweat spot, but after that the accumulation of rounding errors prevales and the results diverge from their expected values.

In OP's case, this calculation

```
area += f(x) + 4*f(y) + f(z);
```

introduces (and accumulates) rounding errors, due to the fact that `area` becomes much greater than `f(x) + 4*f(y) + f(z)` (e.g 224678.937 vs. 0.3606823). The bigger `n` is, the sooner this gets relevant, making the result diverging from the real one.

As mentioned in the comments, another issue (undefined behavior) is that `area` isn't initialized (to zero).